# How to get parameter of my Annotation as a validator?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-validator

I created my own Annotation to validate my REST parameter like this:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public User createUser(@UserConstraint("CREATE_MODE") @RequestBody User user) 
    {   //code        }
```

I got everything working where my ConstraintValidator is called to validate the User input, but I can't figure out how to get the parameter of my own annotation. I want to read the value CREATE_MODE.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserConstraint {
    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    public String value();
}
```

How to access??

```
public class UserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserConstraint, User> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(User user,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void initialize(UserConstraint annotation) {
        // initialization, probably not needed
        mode = annotation.value();
    }
```